# Reordering type parameters in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I have a question about type parameters that I think is best expressed by an example. This piece of code

```
newtype Triple a b c = T (a,b,c)

instance Functor (Triple a b) where
    fmap f (T (x, y, z)) = T (x, y, (f z))
```

expresses triples as functors in their third variable.

1. How would I turn them into functors in their second variable?
2. How would I turn actual tuples (not my new type) into a functor?

The general question is: suppose I have a parametric type `m a b c d e` how do I express the parametric type `m a b d e` obtained by fixing one parameter? Or equivalently, how do I express the parametric type `m a b d e c` obtained by making an arbitrary parameter the last one?

Edit: it may not have become quite clear what I mean, so I'm trying to clarify: `Triple` has kind `* -> * -> * -> *`. So I can partially evaluate at two types to get something of kind `* -> *` which could be `Functor` or some other parametrized class. This evaluation is easy to do at the first two parameters but it is in principle possible at any two of the parameters, and I am asking how it can be done. This is essentially asking for a `flip` on the level of types.

As a concrete use case I can have three parametrized classes Functor, Foo, and Bar, and I want (Triple _ b c) to be a Functor, (Triple a _ c) to be a Foo, and (Triple a b _) to be a Bar (for all a, b, c). So then `Triple a b c` would be a `Functor`, a `Foo` and a `Bar`. You would think of writing these one-parameter types  `a -> Triple a b c`, `b -> Triple a b c` and `c -> Triple a b c` but of course this literal notation expresses mapping types.

Edit2: Before posting a question on stackoverflow I always try to strip it to its abstract core, but this seems to obscure what I actually want. So a concrete variant of this question can now be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079676/partially-evaluated-type-in-classes).

Comment: You might think that using the `TypeSysnonymInstances` ghc extension you could do `type TripleSynonym a c b = (a, b, c)` and then `instance Functor (TripleSynonym a c)` but no: ghc doesn't let you partially evaluate the type in this case.

Answer (score 3):

This is what newtypes are for. You wrap an existing type up in a newtype, letting you do different stuff to it at the type level while leaving the value level unchanged. For example:

```
newtype SecondTriple a b c = SecondTriple (a, c, b)

instance Functor (SecondTriple a b) where
  fmap f (SecondTriple (x, z, y)) = SecondTriple (x, f z, y)
```

If you like, you can wrap Triple instead of wrapping `(,,)`, but of course you can't use Triple's Functor instance anyway so it's not much help.

Comment: There are two problems I have with this suggestion: 1. if I introduce a new type for all the permutations of a type with n parameters that will give me a lot of new types (n!); 2. I might actually want a tuple to be a functor wrt. the first argument and to be in some other class wrt. the second argument.

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case you might get what you need by using lenses.

The combination of [over](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#v:over) and [all the functions in the tuple module (_1, _2, _3 etc.)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19/docs/Control-Lens-Tuple.html) gives you the ability to lift functions into more tuple positions than just the rightmost one.

EDIT Adding an example.

So say we have this tuple.

```
(1, "Foo", True)
```

And we want to `(+ 1)` to the value in its first position.

```
> import Control.Lens (over, _1)
> over _1 (+ 1) (1, "Foo", True)
(2,"Foo",True)
```

Or upper-case the string in its second position

```
> import Data.Char (toUpper)
> import Control.Lens (over, _2)
> over _2 (map toUpper) (1, "Foo", True)
(1,"FOO",True)
```

Or perhaps we want to flip the bool in its third position

```
> import Control.Lens (over, _3)
> over _3 not (1, "Foo", True)
(1,"Foo",False)
```

Comment: Would you care to spell out an example? It sure seems like a sufficient level of abstraction but I'm not familiar with lenses.

Comment: Sure thing, added to the answer.

Comment: Thank you! But how does this work on the level of types? Essentially I want to change the kind of triple.

Comment: Hrm, what I’ve given you there is how you might lift functions into different tuple positions. It seemed to me that would be useful given it _sort of_ makes tuples Functors in whichever position you like. I’d need to know more about what you’re trying to do, I think, to help more. Is there some reason you _have_ to use Functor?

Comment: Ah, I also realise that in all my examples there you can’t see that it’s possible to change the type of a position. That is: `over _1 @(,,)` should have the type `(a -> d) -> (a, b, c) -> (d, b, c)`

Comment: I get the impression that this can be helpful but I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

A functor has kind `Type -> Type`, so `Triple :: Type -> Type -> Type -> Type` itself is not a functor; only the nearly-saturated partial application `Triple a b` for 2 types `a` and `b` can be a functor.

`Triple` *is*, however, an example of a "trifunctor", which you can define yourself.

```
class Trifunctor p where
    trimap :: (a -> x) -> (b -> y) -> (c -> z) -> p a b c -> p x y z
    -- There are only so many synonyms for first, second, etc
    map13 :: (a -> x) -> p a b c -> p x y z
    map13 f = trimap f id id
    map23 :: (b -> y) -> p a b c -> p x y z
    map23 f = trimap id f id
    map33 :: (c -> z) -> p a b c -> p x y z
    map33 f = trimap id id f

instance Trifunctor Triple where
    trimap f g h (Triple x y z) = Triple (f x) (g y) (h z)
```

The pattern generalizes; the product of `n` types is an `n`-functor.

Comment: Thank you, I was being imprecise. I would like to say something like "Triple a _ c" is a functor, "Triple a b _" is a foo and "Triple _ b c" is a bar.

Comment: You can't. All type classes have kind `* -> Constraint`, where `*` is some particular kind. Type constructors are curried just like functions, so `Triple a _ c` isn't a valid partial application to produce a kind.

Comment: To be more specific, you *can* say, for instance that `Triple` is *functorial* in its second argument, "foo-like" in its third, and "bar-like" in its first. (For some concrete examples, a bifunctor is functoriall in both its arguments, and a profunctor is contrafunctorial in its first and functorial in its second.) Some notion of composition of type classes would be needed for what you want, and as far as I know, Haskell doesn't have anything like that. (I also don't know if the lack would be due to a limitation of the language, or just the lack of a library that implements it.)

Comment: (Or rather, that `Triple` could be an *instance* of some type class that describes the bar-likeness, functoriality, and foo-likeness of its instances.)