# Partially evaluated type in classes

Tags: haskell, types

This is a concrete version of my question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60072003/reordering-type-parameters-in-haskell). I have an algorithm that produces some output and can produce some auxiliary information, which I may or may not care about in a given case (I call this auxiliary information "annotation" below). I am using Euclid's algorithm for an illustration:

```
class AnnotatedGcd m where
    actually :: (Integral a) => a -> m a
    update :: (Integral a) => a -> m a -> m a

newtype GcdOnly a = Gcd a deriving Show

instance AnnotatedGcd GcdOnly where
    actually = Gcd
    update q = id

newtype GcdWithSteps a = GcdS (a, Int) deriving Show

instance AnnotatedGcd GcdWithSteps where
    actually x = GcdS (x, 0)
    update q (GcdS (x, s)) = GcdS (x, s+1)

newtype GcdExtended a = GcdE (a, a, a) deriving Show

instance AnnotatedGcd GcdExtended where
    actually x = GcdE (x, 1, 0)
    update q (GcdE (x, k, l)) = (GcdE (x, l, k - q*l))

gcd :: (Integral a, AnnotatedGcd m) => a -> a -> m a
gcd a b = if b == 0 then actually a else update q ((Main.gcd) b r)
  where q = a `div` b
        r = a `rem` b
```

The function `gcd a b` returns an `AnnotatedGcd` which in the example could be `GcdOnly` which is just the gcd g, or it could be `GcdWithSteps` in addition counting how many steps it took, or it could be `GcdExtended` also providing coefficients k,l such that g = k * a + l * b:

```
*Main> (Main.gcd 253 83) :: (GcdOnly Int)
Gcd 1
*Main> (Main.gcd 253 83) :: (GcdWithSteps Int)
GcdS (1,4)
*Main> (Main.gcd 253 83) :: (GcdExtended Int)
GcdE (1,21,-64)
```

Now what if I want to count the number of steps *and* get the coefficients? Rather than keeping writing more and more instances of `AnnotatedGcd` I would want to have the notion of an annotation and say that tuples of annotations are annotations again:

```
class GcdAnnotation a where
    emptyAnnotation :: a
    annotate :: Integral b => b -> a -> a

instance (GcdAnnotation a, GcdAnnotation b) => GcdAnnotation (a,b) where
    emptyAnnotation = (emptyAnnotation, emptyAnnotation)
    annotate q (x, y) = (annotate q x, annotate q y)

instance (GcdAnnotation a, GcdAnnotation b, GcdAnnotation c) => GcdAnnotation (a,b,c) where
    emptyAnnotation = (emptyAnnotation, emptyAnnotation, emptyAnnotation)
    annotate q (x, y, z) = (annotate q x, annotate q y, annotate q z)

instance GcdAnnotation b => AnnotatedGcd (,b) where
    actually x = (x, emptyAnnotation)
    update q (g, x) = (g, annotate q x)
```

This is valid Haskell code except for the last instance declaration. The question is: how could one actually make such a declaration?

The general version would be: given two parametric classes `Class a` and `Class b` how can one turn tuples `(a,b)` into instances of both classes (one with respect to the first parameter, one with respect to the second).

Comment: "one with respect to the first parameter" Unfortunately the answer is the same as amalloy's answer there: this simply isn't something Haskell allows and you need `newtype`. For exchanging two parameters (or the last two if there are more) you can use `Flip (,) b` (see http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TypeCompose-0.9.14/docs/Control-Compose.html). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335967/manipulating-the-order-of-arguments-to-type-constructors.

Comment: Thank you, this is disappointing but very helpful! The discussion in the question you are referencing is of the kind I was hoping for (except for the conclusion).